Using Comparison Logic in SearchKit Output
I'm trying to use SearchKit to create mailing group for all of our organization's donors. The problem is that some of the donations come through a 3rd party account (DAF) but of course we want to thank the donors themselves rather than the DAF.
Therefore, some donations contain a field called "Acknowledgment Contact ID" in which the contact information for the actual donor is stored. I can get SearchKit to find all of the appropriate information, and to group the contribution records using logic GROUP BY: IF NULL "Acknowlegment ID", "CONTACT ID" - which works perfectly.
The problem is that I'd like to then make a smart group which includes BOTH the Acknowledgment IDs and the Contact IDs. I can't figure out a way to make the search display both types of contact IDs in a single column, using the same conditional logic as the 'group by' criteria. Only the aggregation options are available on the "Select Fields" area.
Obviously I could create two different smart groups and merge them, but I'm trying to be efficient here.

Try adding "Acknowlegment ID" as a column to your search and then click the Fx button and select IF NULL to coalesce it with the id. Then use that as the id column for your smart group.

Thank you! This is what I had already been trying, however I'm not seeing the "if null" option in the drop-down when I add that to the columns in "select fields"- I only get average, first, last, count, etc. Any thoughts on why that would be?

Ok I figured out why the option wasn't showing up - it was because I was aggregating results using "group by". So now I can make the appropriate column but then still am not seeing the option to use a calculated column to create a smart group. Am I missing this somewhere?
